# linq with null condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

How can the foll. sql be written in Linq. I am using LinqToEntities,C#.
@companyID & @branchID are the parameters

```
select * from tblEmp e
where e.deleted = 0 and
(e.companyId = @companyID OR e.companyid is null) and
(e.branchId = @branchID OR e.branchid is null)
```

For now, there is a stored procedure for the same and I am using it in linq, like this:

```
var qry = from d in MYDB.GetData(int companyid, int branchid)
select new
{
//all reqd. columns...
}
```

so, is it possible to write the above in Linq, directly.

**EDIT:**

```
public IEnumerable<tblEmp> GetData(Guid gCID, Guid gBID)
{
  var employees = (from e in tblEmp
                 where !e.deleted
                 && (e.companyId == gCID || e.companyid == null)
                 && (e.branchId == gBID || e.branchid == null)
                 select e
                 ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

//Both Parameters are '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'. I am expecting all records but the count is 0. Where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

```
var employees = (from e in tblEmp
                 where !e.deleted
                 && (e.companyId == aCompanyIdHere || e.companyid == null)
                 && (e.branchId == aBranchIdHere || e.branchid == null)
                 select new
                 {
                     e.Id,
                     e.companyId,
                     e.branchId
                 });
```

## Edit

The query should work, but I suspect you requirements are a bit different.
If you want to get all items when a passed in parameter `Guid` is empty you could do the following.

```
public IEnumerable<tblEmp> GetData(Guid gCID, Guid gBID)
{
    var employees = (from e in tblEmp
                     where !e.deleted
                     && (gCID == Guid.Empty || e.companyid == gCID)
                     && (gBID == Guid.Empty || e.branchid == gBID)
                     select e
                     ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

But for better readability IMO:

```
public IEnumerable<tblEmp> GetData(Guid? gCID, Guid? gBID)
{
    var employees = (from e in tblEmp
                     where !e.deleted
                     && (gCID == null || e.companyid == gCID)
                     && (gBID == null || e.branchid == gBID)
                     select e
                     ).AsEnumerable();
}
```

and pass in `null` instead of `Guid.Empty` if you want all records.

```
var data = GetData(null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this work if the datatype is guid instead of int. There are records in DB, but I get 0 count. I have updated my Question what I have tried.

Comment: @Ruby No problem, it really depends on your needs. I'm more concerned about the caller here :) `GetData(Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty)` vs `GetData(null, null)`, but to each his own I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var qry = (
    from test in MYDB.tblEmp
    where !e.deleted
        && (e.companyId == "any id" || e.companyid == null)
        && (e.branchId == "anyid" || e.branchid == null)
    select test
).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Perhaps you're accidentally right, but I don't see a `TOP 1` in his query anywhere.